# How to make `import` and `from import` diverge in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, attributeerror

Say I have the following consecutive lines in a python code base:

```
from foo import BAR          # succeeds
log.info(f"{dir(BAR)=}")     # succeeds
import foo.BAR               # succeeds
log.info(f"{dir(foo.BAR)=}") # fails, AttributeError no field BAR in module foo
```

There's no other code in between. If I deliberately wanted to create this effect, how would I do it? I know it's possible because I'm observing it in a large code base running under Python 3.11, but I have no idea how. **What feature of the python import system lets these two forms of import diverge?** It seems like the ability to `import foo.BAR` must require `foo.BAR` to exist, and we even confirm it exists first with `from foo import BAR` and logging the fields of `BAR`.

`foo` is a directory. `foo/__init__.py` exists and is empty. `foo/BAR.py` exists and contains top level items like functions and classes.

Comment: Maybe you will need to include additional debugging information, like verify what `BAR` actually is (a simpler `print` will suffice) and also try to use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) on whatever `foo.BAR` actually is and produce that output, i.e. `print(importlib.import_module('foo.bar'))` vs `print(importlib.import_module('.bar', 'foo'))`, because this cannot be naively reproduced (this is a rather peculiar behavior and so there will be curiosity as to how this can happen, as there may be an importer that caused this).

Comment: Basically, you will need to ensure that both output actually point to the exact same thing, because we don't have access to the Python code base you have referred to in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen due to dynamic imports. Typical code to do a dynamic import looks like this:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
new_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = new_module
```

However, if `module_name` has multiple `.` separated parts, e.g. `foo.bar.buzz`, then this diverges from typical Python import behavior in two ways.

1. Normally if you write `import foo.bar.buzz` python will first `import foo` then `import foo.bar` then `import foo.bar.buzz`. The code above doesn't reproduce this behavior.
2. Additionally, Python takes care of setting an attribute on the parent module for each child module in order to make references like `foo.child` work.

So mimicking Python's regular import behavior for `foo.bar` requires:

1. Importing `foo` and setting `sys.modules["foo"]`.
2. Importing `foo.bar` and setting `sys.modules["foo.bar"]`.
3. Setting the `bar` attribute on the `foo` module object to point at bar. You can do this with `setattr(foo, "bar", bar)` where `foo` and `bar` are the module objects returned from `module_from_spec`.

Answer (score 1):

`foo.BAR` needs to be a *module* for `import foo.BAR` to work.
If `BAR` is an *attribute* of `foo`, then it won't. E.g.:

```
# foo.py
BAR = 'baz'
```

You can't `import foo.BAR` the above. However, you *can* `from foo import BAR` the above.

---

In response to your edits, I cannot reproduce that:

```bash
% ls foo
BAR.py      __init__.py
% more foo/BAR.py
BAZ = 42
% python3 -c 'import foo.BAR; import logging; logging.error(f"{dir(foo.BAR)=}")'
ERROR:root:dir(foo.BAR)=['BAZ', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

Comment: I edited to add some details, this is happening even though foo is a directory and BAR.py is a file inside

Comment: Also the `import foo.bar` succeeds! It's accessing `foo.BAR` afterwards that fails

Comment: Can't reproduce that behaviour here.